# Using a minimal set of certificate authoraties

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority

It been [known](http://www.thoughtcrime.org/blog/ssl-and-the-future-of-authenticity/) for quite a while now that SSL is more of a security-illusion than a real one.

As it's not completely useless, and there's no real alternative at moment (though [convergence](http://convergence.io/) looks interesting), I'd like to try using a "minimal" set of CAs, assuming that the biggest 3 will cover ~70% of the internet, and all common websites in particular.

My question is:
**Is there such a minimal CA set?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer: No.**
I think you won't be happy with only three CAs. Lots of clicking around certificate warnings. This will not make your browsing safer.

Also reconsider what you are trying to achieve. I'm assuming, that you want to protect yourself from rogue and/or exploited CAs. So that means CAs that will issue certificates for google.com, etc, when Google never asked them to do that. And those certificates could then be used to eavesdrop on google.com visitors.

So, yeah, if you exclude obscure Dutch/Turkish (re. DigitNotar hack, re. Turktrust hack) CAs from your trust store, then you won't be affected if that CA is hacked. -- As has in fact happened in the past.

What you won't be protected from, is if a Sub-CA, subsidiary or reseller of your trusted CAs is hacked. This has also happened in the past. (Comodo Brazil for example.)

**So what will help now?**
What will however protect you, is if you use a browser, that supports certificate pinning.
Like Google Chrome for example. They have built in "Pin-Sets" for certain sites. (Google, Facebook, Twitter, etc.)

They will not a allow a certificate issued by other than a few trusted CAs to be accepted.

**What workarounds exist, but are too bothersome?**
What I tried for a while is the "[Certificate Patrol](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/certificate-patrol/versions/)" Firefox extension. (Last updated in 2011.)
It alarms you, when you see new certificates for a site. And then asks you to answer yes or no.

I found it too noisy to be useful for me.

There is a nice write up in chapter 5 of this PDF here:
2013-12-03, Mariana Isabel Oliveira Taveira & Thiago Sobral Marques da Silva,  [SSL Certificates and HTTPS -- Issues in the current Web Trust Model for Digital Certification](http://web.fe.up.pt/~jmcruz/seginf/seginf.1314/trabs-als/final/G3-digital.certific.issues-final-rev2.pdf)

**What might help in the future?**
What might also help in the future is "[Certificate Transparency](http://www.certificate-transparency.org/)". Where the concept is that even though fraudulent certificates may be generated, at least there will be an audit trail.

And that certificates without audit trails are rejected right away. The idea being that when a CA hack is discovered:

- (a) the cleanup can be done much easier. All issued certificates are in the audit trail and can be revoked in bulk.
- (b) this may make it easier to discover a CA hack in the first place. As all audit trails are public.

CT is in the process of being phased in -- again leading the effort is Google Chrome -- but it is not being enforced anywhere yet.

---

That being said, if you really want to go ahead and create a 3-CA-trust-store then read on below.

**Three largest CAs: Comodo, Symantec, GoDaddy**
This article says the three largest surveyed (what ever that means) are Comodo, Symantec and GoDaddy.

W³Techs.com, [Usage of SSL certificate authorities for websites](http://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/ssl_certificate/all) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/TtOPY).)

So you could try to make your minimal CA set with those three CAs.

Comment: How do i access the pin setting mechanism on chrome?

Comment: You don't. There is no user interface. Instead Webmasters must explicitly ask Google via a website: "Please include this pin in your next pinset!" and set a special HTTP header on their website. -> I've added a section above that mentions the "Certificate Patrol" Firefox addon. Maybe you'll like that.

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff this is a VERY good answer. Thank you, and sorry I can't upvote it yet. As Comodo turns out to be one of the big-3, the idea is completely useless.